# How AddHandler from C# DLL to VB Proj

Tags: c#, vb.net, dll, addhandler

Someone know how addhandlers from C# DLL to VB App. When I try to use AddHandler into my VB project, the Visual Studio returns:

```
Error   BC30676 'DebugMessageEvent' is not an event of 'Debugger'...
```

The Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent is a part of a DLL called DLLNAMESPACE with his own class called Debugger and send information about the others methods and process from their other classes within DLL called DLLNAMESPACE

[image]

If I go to the 'DebugMessageEvent' definition from VB Proj (Auto-Converted from the DLL called DLLNAMESPACE), I get the follow code:

```
Public Class Debugger
    Public DebugMessageEvent As EventHandler(Of DebugMessageArgs)

    Public Shared ReadOnly Property Instance As Debugger

    Public Class DebugMessageArgs
        Inherits EventArgs

        Public Sub New()

        Public Property Message As Object
    End Class
End Class
```

### The VB Project (Doesn't Work)

```
Imports DLLNAMESPACE
Public Class myclass
    ...
    Private Sub backup(...)
        AddHandler Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent, AddressOf console_DebugMessageEvent
        ...
    End Sub
    ...
    Private Sub console_DebugMessageEvent(sender As Object, e As Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

### Another C# Project (Works)

```
using DLLNAMESPACE;
public partial class myclass : Form
{
    ...
    private void backup()
    {
        Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent += console_DebugMessageEvent;
        ...
    }
    ...

    void console_DebugMessageEvent(object sender, Debugger.DebugMessageArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
    ...
}
```

[image]

### The DLL C# Code

```
using System;
namespace DLLNAMESPACE
{
    public sealed class Debugger
    {
        private static readonly Lazy<Debugger> instance = new Lazy<Debugger>(() => new Debugger());

        private Debugger()
        {

        }

        public static Debugger Instance
        {
            get { return instance.Value; }
        }

        public EventHandler<DebugMessageArgs> DebugMessageEvent;

        public class DebugMessageArgs : EventArgs
        {
            public object Message { get; set; }
        }

        private void RaiseDebugMessageEvent(object message)
        {
            DebugMessageEvent?.Invoke(this, new DebugMessageArgs
            {
                Message = message
            });
        }

        internal void DebugMessage(object data)
        {
            RaiseDebugMessageEvent(data);
        }
    }
}
```

All the rest of DLL functions works as expected. Please advice, I don't want to change the code of the DLL, just the VB.NET code

### Some unsuccessful tests

Pass Visual Studio verification, but others background process associated to DLLNAMESPACE closes.

#### New EventHandler

```
Imports DLLNAMESPACE
Public Class myclass
    ...
    Private Sub backup(...)
        Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = New EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)(AddressOf console_DebugMessageEvent)
        ...
    End Sub
    ...
    Private Sub console_DebugMessageEvent(sender As Object, e As Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Consola RoboSharp: " & e.Message)
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

#### DirectCast

```
Imports DLLNAMESPACE
Public Class myclass
    ...
    Private Sub backup(...)
        Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent, DirectCast(AddressOf console_DebugMessageEvent, EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs))), EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs))
        ...
    End Sub
    ...
    Private Sub console_DebugMessageEvent(sender As Object, e As Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)
        Console.WriteLine("Consola RoboSharp: " & e.Message)
    End Sub
    ...
End Class
```

If someone have time to recreate my problem, try using robosharp from nuget and add it to your vb.net project

Comment: Sorry for that, I didn't read the question thoroughly. I believe Dave's answer should solve your problem then.

Comment: Why don't you just make a C# dll of your own which handles this for you?

Answer (score 1):

'DebugMessageEvent' is not an event, so you can't treat it as such with 'AddHandler'. It's a field of a delegate type, so you can instead use the following:

```
Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent, DebugMessage), EventHandler(Of DebugMessageArgs))
```

Comment: I get an error (copy&paste) with Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent, console_DebugMessageEvent), EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs))

Argument not specified for parameter 'sender' of 'Private Sub console_DebugMessageEvent(sender As Object, e As Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)'.

I changed my question with more details

Thanks

Comment: @EliasRodriguezPizarro : This works for me: `Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = DirectCast(System.Delegate.Combine(Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent, DirectCast(AddressOf console_DebugMessageEvent, EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs))), EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs))`

Comment: @EliasRodriguezPizarro : You have to cast the method as an `EventHandler(Of Debugger.DebugMessageArgs)`. :)

Answer (score 0):

If the `Delegate.Combine()` solution causes the other applications using the DLL to crash, it seems to me that the best solution would be to create a C# DLL to add the handler for you.

For instance:

```
using System;

namespace DebuggerHelperDLL
{
    public static class DebuggerHelper
    {
        public static void AddHandler(EventHandler<Debugger.DebugMessageArgs> eventHandler)
        {
            Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent += eventHandler;
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your VB.NET project:

```vb
DebuggerHelper.AddHandler(AddressOf console_DebugMessageEvent)
```

---

It seems strange though that it wouldn't work since the compiled C# DLL using the `+=` operator yields this when decompiled into IL:

```
.method public hidebysig static 
    void AddHandler (
            class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger/DebugMessageArgs> eventHandler
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x211c
    // Code size 29 (0x1d)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: call class DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger::get_Instance()
    IL_0006: dup
    IL_0007: ldfld class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger/DebugMessageArgs> DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger::DebugMessageEvent
    IL_000c: ldarg.0
    IL_000d: call class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate, class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
    IL_0012: castclass class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger/DebugMessageArgs>
    IL_0017: stfld class [mscorlib]System.EventHandler`1<class DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger/DebugMessageArgs> DLLNAMESPACE.Debugger::DebugMessageEvent
    IL_001c: ret
} // end of method DebuggerHelper::AddHandler
```

As you see on offset `IL_000d`, it calls `System.Delegate::Combine()`:

```
call class [mscorlib]System.Delegate [mscorlib]System.Delegate::Combine(class [mscorlib]System.Delegate, class [mscorlib]System.Delegate)
```

Comment: same result, ill mod the DLL

Comment: @EliasRodriguezPizarro : Darn. Why couldn't the author of the DLL just've made an ordinary event? :( -- Out of interest, what do you mean when you say "mod"? Modify?

Comment: yes modify the dll with the souce of robosharp. thanks for your time, also, other guy, in other forum awnser:

`Dim handler As New EventHandler(Of DebugMessageEventArgs)(AddressOf yourHandler)
Debugger.Instance.DebugMessageEvent = handler`